# Scala declare class with default value for field

Tags: scala

I am trying to declare a `Trie` class, which has a `root` field, that is initialized to `null`.

```
class Trie(root: TrieNode = null) {
```

I am trying to instantiate it like this:

```
Trie trie = new Trie();
```

However, I get the following error(`Solution` is the object containing all my code):

```
error: value trie is not a member of object Solution.Trie
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error. Unlike java, you need to declare whether the field is val (equivalent to final in java) or var (can be changed after first assignment).

You need to declare it like this:

```
val trie = new Trie()
```

Or:

```
var trie = new Trie()
```

Comment: There's no need for the type `:Trie`.  The compiler will work it out.

Comment: It is less readable in my opinion. Also not idiomatic scala. Both will work of course